# Is it possible to set the background of an Html video element when user stops it?

Tags: html, html5-video

When pausing a video, the last frame is shown in the element, how can I clear the element so the frame will be cleared and the initial background style of the element will be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by looking on an example code. The key is to stop the transmission by connection.close() so no new blobs will come from the sender, and to set the src of the video of the receiver to empty string.

```
 var connection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: _iceServers });
 ...
   // Close the connection between myself and the given partner
    _closeConnection = function () {
        if (_connection) {
            _onStreamRemovedCallback(null, null);

            // Close the connection
            _connection.close();
        }
    },
 onStreamRemoved: function (connection, streamId) {
            // todo: proper stream removal.  right now we are only set up for one-on-one which is         why this works.
            console.log('removing remote stream from partner window');

            // Clear out the partner window
            var otherVideo = document.querySelector('.video.partner');
            otherVideo.src = '';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onpause = function() {
    // change background color of element or add overlay to the element
};
```